# Javadocs link to external javadoc

Tags: java, documentation, javadoc

I am generating Javadocs. Now I would like to automatically link all library- and JDK classes to the official docs of that lib or JDK. Is that possible, and if so, which command line args do i need

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Resolving references to the standard Java classes requires you have a local copy of the Java Docs.

The JDK 7 JavaDocs are available [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) under Additional Resources

Then, run javadoc, with the `-link` option.
It takes the URL of the documents you want to reference (ex, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/).