# javadoc task in gradle - link to oracle's javadoc instead of displaying unlinked qualified class names everywhere

Tags: java, gradle, javadoc

In the javadoc that my project generates, every time a class from a standard java library is referenced, it inserts a not linked qualified class name.

What I want to have happen is a link being generated instead pointing to the [oracle.com Java SE 8 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html).

Example:

> static [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/String.html)

(or it could link to the not framed version instead)

instead of

> static java.lang.String

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580248/javadocs-link-to-external-javadoc

Comment: @Sergey Consider writing a good answer and getting that reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible by appending `-link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/<javaversion>/docs/api/` to the command line arguments passed to javadoc.

Refer to the documentation of your build tool or IDE on how to do that.

Answer (score 4):

Add the following to your Gradle script:

```
javadoc {
    options {
        links 'https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/'
    }
}
```

(Or `https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/` if you want to link to Javadocs for Java 11.)