# Where/how can I download the Geb API Documentation

Tags: geb

I am in the process of creating javadocs for all of my page objects and modules. When I generate the java docs, any links to Geb documentation do not work.

According to this stack overflow question: [Javadocs link to external javadoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580248/javadocs-link-to-external-javadoc)

one would need a local copy of the documentation in order to interface to 2 sets of documentation, but I am not sure where I go to download the Geb documentation in this fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do this without downloading the documentation by configuring a groovy task like so and running it.

```
groovydoc{
    docTitle = "My GroovyDoc"
    windowTitle = "Page Objects GroovyDoc"
    groovyClasspath = configurations.groovyDoc
    destinationDir = new File(<My File Path>)
    link("http://gebish.org/manual/current/api/", "geb")
}
```