# Javadoc Link to External Document Not Working

Tags: java, javadoc

When running the `javadoc` command, I am unable to "link" to the Java SE packages as described in the Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/javadoc/javadoc-command.htm#JSJAV-GUID-C27CE557-E5C6-4688-9FA5-9E9DE886A569), as well as in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17580248/javadocs-link-to-external-javadoc). Running the command...

```
javadoc -link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api com.mypackage
```

... doesn't replace the method signatures and return type labels of Java SE classes with links. Oddly enough, there are no warnings on the command line to indicate that something went wrong. The JavaDoc is generated as if the `-link` option hadn't even been included. What could be the problem?

Comment: I have the sae problem. I can only add that if you use `https:` at least you get a warning.